# slang for the litteral translation "Have you become human?"

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm doing an English subtitle for my short film. There's this scene where a notorious character is trying to act like a good person but another guy who's used to know him tells sarcastically [a literal translation] "Have you become a human?" What is a good slang/expression for such a

Comment: I don't hardly recognise you any more, Sabata.

Answer (score 1):

This typically doesn't come up in discussion:

- "Are *you* becoming a human?" //directed toward a cold person
- "Do I sense a little emotion?" //for someone who exhibits a cold shoulder
- "Do I detect kindness?" //for someone who seems robotic
- "Oh, so you're human now?" //for someone who is a sociopath
- "Woke up with feelings today *did we?*" //not really the same.
- "Finally, *a real boy?*" //a play on Pinnochio
- "That's noble." //Response to the phrase, but not a direct translation
- "Are you for real?" //calling someone on their atypical response.
- "For real?" //shortened version of the last one, more slang.

Comment: Thanks. "Oh, so you're human now?" seem to fit more but is it really common? Let me make the context clearer: A: [takes out a cigarette and asks] Do you have lights? B: I don't smoke anymore. A: "Oh, so you're human now?" Does it fit?

Comment: I've mostly got "for real" out of people since I am most like the sociopathic robot who frequently does not respond to someone empathetically. I would use "Oh, so you're human now" coming from a female or effeminate male to a male. "Are you becoming a human" would be male to male. "For real" or "For realz" coming from a teen. "Are you for real" is a cultural phrase.